# convert a greyscale image to RGB

Tags: image-processing

I have a **greyscale image** which was created from a **RGB image** using farmula:
`0.3 * c.r + 0.59 * c.g + 0.11 * c.b`
Now, I want to convert the greyscale image back to the RGB color image close to original as far as possible.
I tried o look for it on the internet, but could not find how to do it. Wikipedia suggests that it is possible but does not explain how.

Could someone please suggest how can I do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_colorization

Comment: If Wikipedia suggests it is possible then we need to correct that. Where exactly does it say that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't think wikipedia suggests there's a formula to do it, rather it talks about the way film makers have done it.

Comment: yes, probably I misinterpreted the words, wiki [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale] says: "The reverse is also possible: to build a full color image from their separate grayscale channels." I somehow missed the part that it can be only done if the grayscale for each channel is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not possible.  You've taken 3D information, and thrown away 2 of the dimensions.  You can't get them back.

Comment: It's worse than that. You started with Hue, Saturation, and Lightness, and threw away everything but Lightness.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get true color values.

Think of it like this:
you have three unknowns and only one equation.

there are infinite solutions that form a two dimensional plane. You can get a poor representation of the image. Just choose two of the values randomly and calculate thethird one. Hope for the best.

you can generate an RGB value from yoru grayscale if you set R=G=B=Grayscale value

Answer (score -3):

yes you cant, there was some method to make greyscale to RGB, in this method its include RGB image as baseimage. i write code about this before but i completely forgot the method name. 
try RGB, alpha beta gamma, some kind like color conversion.